# Can I pass an entire javascript object to Node.js for server processing?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Currently, I serialize a large javascript object and post it to the server. This process takes to long. So, I would like to pass a javascript object from the client to the server via node.js/socket.io so the server can handle the workload. It seems that it does not work. Is this possible?

Comment: Should you? You are creating a security hole that can be easily exploited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the slowdown? If the performance issue is related to serialization, then you're faced with the same problem no matter how you communicate with the server - can't ship objects around without serializing them first.

(To send the object over socket.io, first serialize it, then send it across as a string)

Comment: Yes, the issue is with serialization (performance hit on the browser causing users to wait until the serialization in complete). Currently, I serialize a large javascript object that is then posted to the server for processing. I was hoping that I could pass the entire object and do all the convertion/processing on the server allowing the users to continue on with other tasks. Is there another  option?

Comment: Serialization means "prepare for transfer". No, if you're looking to transfer the object, you can't offload the work. Look at other methods for mitigating your problem - transferring sub-sections of the object when they change, caching some of the serialization work, and making the object smaller overall, are standard techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, No it is not possible.  You are essentially message passing between two distinct systems.  The fact that they are both javascript interpreters is irrelevant.

I would suggest serializing and passing parts of the object as changes occur.